# I can't connect view.py and url.py to html files

Tags: python, django

I have been learning Django and now working on the topic so-called "template tagging". It's the process to connect views.py file to HTML using "url" function. But I've gotten the message from Anaconda prompt when I tried to run the code, "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'". How can I make this program work? The code is below.

・app_file/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request,"My_app/index.html")

def second(request):
    return render(request,"My_appp/second.html")

def third(request):
    return render(request,"My_app/third.html")
```

・project_file/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from My_app import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url("lp",views.index,name="lp"),
    url("My_app/",include("My_app.urls"))
]
```

・my_app/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from My_app import views
from django.conf.urls import url

app_name = "My_app"

urlpatterns =[
    url("second/",views.second,name="second"),
    url("third/",views.third,name="third")
]
```

・template/app_file/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load statics %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Django Practice</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">`enter code here`
      <div class="jambotron">
        <h1>PAGE FOR INDEX</h1>
        <a href="{% url 'My_app:second' %}">LINK TO SECOND.HTML</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

・template/app_file/second.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jambotron">
          <a href="{% url 'My_app:third' %}">LINK TO THIRD.HTML</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

・template/app_file/third.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
          <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">LINK TO ADMIN PAGE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try to run this code, anaconda prompt says

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yuto1\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjango\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\yuto1\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjango\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\yuto1\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjango\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\yuto1\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\yuto1\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\yuto1\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\yuto1\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\yuto1\Anaconda3\envs\MyDjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 101, in check_url_settings
    if value and not value.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'"
```

Comment: url("lp/",views.index,name="lp"), # 'lp' need suffix a '/'

Comment: Thank you for commenting on my question. I fixed it but still get the same error message. If you could have any idea what's going on, would you help me a little bit more?

Comment: I create a new project and run your codes and didn't see any error, everything is work.

Why not try `path()` instead of `url()`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Include views file in urls.py file and then create path according to it.
from my_app.views import index, second, third. In, place of URL use path. Include your app in setings.py file